# How to validate an xhtml file against a specified DTD?

Tags: c#, validation, xhtml, dtd

I have got my resource file with the help of

```
string filePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name+"." + resourceFileName;    
Stream fileStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(filePath);
```

Now i have to use fileStream to compare my xhtml file against the DTDs that are embedded inside the resource file. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer I thought I knew ([XmlValidatingReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.aspx)) is now deprecated/obsolete depending on your platform, but the replacement seems straightforward. Examples [here](http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/Xml/ValidationReadingXML.aspx) and [here](http://jerrytech.blogspot.com/2008/12/validate-xmlxsd-using-xmlreadersettings.html).

Comment: There's also straight-forward documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2adhb2f.aspx .

Comment: In this case, the documentation /is/ actually straight-forward.  Not guaranteed for MSDN, I know. :)