# Want to use XPath to ensure that an XHTML element has a parent a with specific name

Tags: c#, xpath, xhtml

## XPath

I have an XHTML document where I want to use XPath to ensure that any element with the `class` attribute set to `block` has `p` as the parent element.

The XPath statement I am using will not catch the offending element in the XHTML below, unless I change the element name of `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>` to e.g. `<b>Lorem ipsum dolor</b>`, or change the XPath statement, replacing `[not(p)]` with e.g. `[not(u)]`. Somehow, the fact that there is a sibling element (`p`) with the same element name as the parent element prevents this from working.

Any ideas of what I should do?

(I have been using http://xpather.com/ to validate my XPath).

**XPath**

```xml
.//*[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," block ")]/parent::*[not(p)]
```

**XHTML**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script>
        </script>
        <meta name="description"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div>
          <kbd class="block"></kbd>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a validation tool instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an xhtml file against a specified DTD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914648/how-to-validate-an-xhtml-file-against-a-specified-dtd)

Comment: Hey @Fildor! Thanks for your quick help! Unfortunately, this won't help me. I need to use XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//*[normalize-space(@class) = "block" and not(parent::p)]
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you! Any idea why `.//*[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," block ")]/parent::*[not(p)]` doesn't work?

Comment: At first, the `.//` starts at the current node. So in comparison to `//` it does not select all possible nodes. Secondly, the `block` test was unnecessary complicated. First adding spaces to check against leading and trailing spaces is not necessary. Thirdly, even if the preceding checks were all successful, you were trying to select the parent node (and not the node that contains the "block"  attribute value) which should also fulfill the predicate  `not(p)`. To make this work, you'd have to use `not(self::p)` instead, which checks if the context node is a `<p>` element itself.

Comment: @MattiasSander if this resolved your question why didn't you accept the answer?